# Link from one html page is not responding in other after linking it using iframe

Tags: html

2nd HTML file

```
 <section id="posec">
      <h2>Project One</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><iframe src="../project_one/project_one.html" width="1350" height="500px"></iframe></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
```

file project one

```
<div>
      <h1>Ayush Singh</h1>
      <p>Gmail: <a href="mailto:singhayush98765@gmail.com">singhayush98765@google.com</a></p>
      <p>LinkedIn: <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ayushsingh023/">ayushsingh023</a></p>
      <p>GitHub: <a href="https://github.com/ayushsingh023">ayushsingh023</a></p>
    </div>
```

I tried to link my project one hiperlink to other HTML file using iframe but the links are not responding in 2nd html file where as only mail link is workin but other 2 are getting error. I am not getting why this issue arises as one out of three link are working but other two not.

Comment: "are getting error" — **What** error?!

Comment: the page refused to connect...this is what I am getting

Comment: @AyushSingh: In your browser's development tools, is there any additional information about the error on the console?  I would suspect those target sites may have policies against being embedded in an `<iframe>`.

Comment: www.linkedin.com refused to connect.

this is the only information available on the console

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)